# How do I install mlfinlab on Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, finance

mlfinlab 1.0.1 requires numpy==1.20.1, but tensorflow 2.4.1 requires numpy~=1.19.2.
I have checked the mlfinlab installation for colab. I have uninstalled tensorflow and upgraded my numpy to 1.20.1. However, the following occurs:
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mlfinlab (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mlfinlab
Without Python 3.8, I won't be able to install the library as it only works on that version. I don't know Colab well enough but there must be a way to select a python version. I'm unable to find out how to upgrade Python on Colab. Upgrading will only upgrade the dependencies.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MlFinLab now works for Google Colab. We have relaxed the python versions and the dependencies.